# Magento2 failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: magento2, nginx, php-7, file-permissions, centos

I have an error in a Magento 2 store and I cannot fix it. On homepage appears this:

```
 Error filtering template: Warning: imagepng(/var/www/domain/pub/media/e**hemes/resized/frontend/e**hemes/slideshow/b/a/image-1.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/domain/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 181
```

File permisions are 777 on media and other subdirectories, also php-gd ..installed.

image-1.png can be accessed directly on browser.

Server Centos, Nginx, PHP 7

Comment: Do not use 777 permissions in a production environment. It leaves your site open to attacks from anyone. It could be an *ownership* issue. What user owns these files?

Comment: a user created by me, not root

Comment: Is your user in the `nginx` group (or same group as the nginx process)?